# Creating new sheets based on existing sheet names

Tags: excel, vba

With my current set of codes, I am only able to get it to create new sheets based on the following existing sheets (001, 002 and 003) as shown in **Screenshot 1**; while Sheets (010, 011 and 012 is left out).

How can I tweak my code to make it such that it'll pick up on the names of existing sheets and create new sheets. For example, in Screenshot 2.

```
Dim x As Long
Dim wkshtCount As Long

For x = 1 To ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count
If InStr(1, Sheets(x).Name, "00") > 0 Then wkshtCount = wkshtCount + 1
Next

Dim i As Long

For i = 1 To wkshtCount
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Main Sheet").Copy _
Before:=ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Main Sheet")
ActiveSheet.Name = "Testing" & " " & "00" & i
Next i
```

Screenshot 1:

[image]

Screenshot 2:

[image]

Comment: The problem is here: `InStr(1, Sheets(x).Name, "00")` this condition is onlye met by values 001, 002, 003 and so on. 010, 011 and 012 will not meet this condition. Change the code or change the sheet names to 0011,0012,0013 and so on.

Also, please note that you are naming the sheet in an icnreading way with `ActiveSheet.Name = "Testing" & " " & "00" & i` so 4th sheet would be `Testing 004` even if it should be `Testing 0010`

Comment: oh right! solved it. updated with an answer. Thanks!

Comment: ActiveSheet.Name = "Testing" & " " & Sheets(i).Name

Comment: decided to use this instead, to copy entire name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dim x As Long
Dim wkshtCount As Long

For x = 1 To ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count
If InStr(1, Sheets(x).Name, "0") > 0 Then wkshtCount = wkshtCount + 1
Next

Dim i As Long

For i = 1 To wkshtCount
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Main Sheet").Copy _
Before:=ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Main Sheet")
ActiveSheet.Name = "Testing" & " " & Sheets(i).Name 
Next i
```